# How can I protect routes based on firebase realtime database data / Flutter / GoRouter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, routes

I'm using GoRouter package for routing, my routes look like this:

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    redirect: (context, state) {
      if (user == null) {
        return '/';
      }
    },
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const AuthPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/tables',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const TablesPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/branch-settings',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const BranchSettingsPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/menu',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const MenuPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/stock',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const StockPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/table-settings',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const TableSettingsPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/expenses',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const ExpensesPage();
        },
      ),
    ]);
```

On AuthPage after user logs in I redirect them the SubConfirmationPage to check if they have an active subscription, SubConfirmationPage connects to database with stream builder and I check whether user has an active subscription or not and return different pages depending on situation.

The problem is If user types the url themselves, this stops working, what I need help on is how do  I nest my pages so SubConfirmationPage is always connected and checks the subscription status.